# Core Data - persistent store can not be created on iOS 5.1

Tags: ios5, core-data, persistence

I get an error when I want to create a persistent store.
When I build for iOS 5.0 there is no error and core data works successfully.

Here's the code for create the persistent store:

```
+ (NSManagedObjectContext *)getContext {

    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                             NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];


    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[basePath stringByAppendingFormat:@"Database.sqlite"]];
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil]];
    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:options error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"error loading persistent store..");
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:storeUrl.path error:nil];
        if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:options error:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            //abort();
        }
    }


    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:persistentStoreCoordinator];

    return context;


}
```

The error log:

```
error loading persistent store..
2012-07-15 13:16:31.440 Partyfinder[8213:707] Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The operation couldn‚Äôt be completed. (Cocoa error 512.)" UserInfo=0xde88ca0 {reason=Failed to create file; code = 1}, {
    reason = "Failed to create file; code = 1";
}
2012-07-15 13:16:31.455 Partyfinder[8213:707] error loading persistent store..
2012-07-15 13:16:31.458 Partyfinder[8213:707] Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The operation couldn‚Äôt be completed. (Cocoa error 512.)" UserInfo=0xdeb5360 {reason=Failed to create file; code = 1}, {
    reason = "Failed to create file; code = 1";
}
2012-07-15 13:16:31.467 Partyfinder[8213:707] error loading persistent store..
2012-07-15 13:16:31.470 Partyfinder[8213:707] Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The operation couldn‚Äôt be completed. (Cocoa error 512.)" UserInfo=0xdeb6680 {reason=Failed to create file; code = 1}, {
    reason = "Failed to create file; code = 1";
}
2012-07-15 13:16:31.483 Partyfinder[8213:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores.  It cannot perform a save operation.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x358fa88f 0x37ca1259 0x36230fe7 0x36299287 0x593e5 0x45917 0x5bfc3 0x5c487 0x5bfc3 0x5bf6b 0x45285 0x5bfc3 0x5a883 0x5e26b 0x358ca433 0x3588f533 0x3588f77b 0x358cead3 0x358ce29f 0x358cd045 0x358504a5 0x3585036d 0x374ec439 0x3335ccd5 0x42119 0x420c4)
terminate called throwing an exception
```

Anyone knows how to resolve the error?

Comment: Try deleting the application from Simulator/Device and run again this might solve your problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the "solution" was that the .sqlite file must have the same name as the project name!